# fragment onResume is in transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Is it possible to find out in `onResume` if a fragment is within a fragment transaction *or* if `onResume` is called due to 'coming back to the app'?**

---

Background:

I want to trigger a network call in on resume if the app is coming back from another app or background but I do not want to trigger that call if the fragment is just created and animating during the transition (I am doing this in `onAnimationEnd` of the animation in `onCreateAnimation` to avoid a laggy animation)

---

Example:

This is my base class for the fragment.

```
abstract class AnimationSafeFragment : Fragment() {

abstract fun onReady()

override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation {
    var animation = super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)

    if (animation == null && nextAnim != 0) {
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, nextAnim)
    }

    animation.let {
        view?.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

        animation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {}

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
                view?.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null)
                onReady()
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {}
        })
    }
    return animation
}
}
```

While each of my fragments that are doing long-lasting network calls implement this abstract class like that:

```
class FragmentX : AnimationSafeFragment() {

override fun onReady() {
    fetchDataWithExpensiveCall()
    updateUIExpensiveCall()
}

override fun onResume() {       
    super.onResume()       
    // call onReady here only if this is coming from background, not from an animation, because then we call it twice
    if (conditionIamLookingFor) {
        onReady()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can maybe put a timer sync to the animation before executing the network call.

Comment: Delaying expensive operations with a timer is bad practice in my opinion

Comment: Well maybe you can delay the loading of data, just hold it on to variable and when the animation is finished, load it.

Comment: It is also good to provide your code so we can identify the best possible way to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, i guess you did not get the question. maybe i am unclear. This is exactly what i am doing. but i want a full loading-trigger if the app is coming from background -> no animation

Comment: Manage with some `boolean`.

Comment: not very elegant. But where would you set it? In `onCreate`?

Comment: "Delaying expensive operations with a timer is bad practice in my opinion":
Why ?, use *Handler().postDelayed()* doesn't affect the main thread.
call your method *onReady()* in *onResume()* after postDelayed() a specific time (500ms for example), doesn't need to call it in *onCreateAnimation*

Comment: By the way, "I want to trigger a network call in on resume if the app is coming back from another app or background", auto call network task in *onResume* or *onStart* is bad practice and UX (especially if the app show loading popup), back is just back, not refresh. I think you should implement *Pull to refresh* instead.

Comment: well, delaying an expensive operation (lets call it expensive operation from now, may it be network, or ui update, video start, audio start) nearly always leads to side effects in my experience and want to avoid it) and feels like a bad implementation. Automatic start of of an expensive operation is needed in my particular case